# Injecting JPA's Entity Manager in Hibernate's EmptyInterceptor

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, audit-logging

I am using JPA-2.0 with Hibernate in my data access layer.

For audit logging purposes, I am using Hibernate's EmptyInterceptor by configuring below property in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"  
                value="com.mycom.audit.AuditLogInterceptor" />
```

Where **AuditLogInterceptor** extends hibernate's '**org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor**'.

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {  

    private Long userId;  

    public AuditLogInterceptor() {}  

    @Override  
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,  
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {  
        // Need to perform database operations using JPA entity manager
        return false;  
    }  

   @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,
            Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        // other code here        
        return false;
    }

    @Override  
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) throws CallbackException {  
        System.out.println("I am on postFlush");
        // other code here 
    }  
}
```

I am using JPA entity manager in data access layer to perform database operations. JPA configuration is like below:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:persistenceUnitName="PersistenceUnit"
        p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:persistence.xml"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My AbstractDAO is :

```
public class AbstractDao<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    private final transient Class<T> persistentClass;

    protected transient EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {

        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public final void setEntityManager(final EntityManager entityMgrToSet) {

        this.entityManager = entityMgrToSet;
    }

    public final Class<T> getPersistentClass() {

        return persistentClass;
    }

    public final void persist(final T entity) {

         entityManager.persist(entity);       
    }

}
```

**I would like to inject JPA entity manager in 'AuditLogInterceptor' so that I can perform database operations in 'AuditLogInterceptor' like my abstract DAO.**

Any Idea? What should be the proper solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have got a simple way to perform database operation using JPA Entity Manager in 'AuditLogInterceptor'

I have created below class that will give the application context reference:

```
@Component("applicationContextProvider")
    public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
        private static ApplicationContext context;

        public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            return context;
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }
    }
```

Created Data access class:

```
@Repository("myAuditDAO")
public class myAuditDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    private final transient Class<T> persistentClass;

    protected transient EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyDAO() {

        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public final void setEntityManager(final EntityManager entityMgrToSet) {

        this.entityManager = entityMgrToSet;
    }

    public final Class<T> getPersistentClass() {

        return persistentClass;
    }

    public final T findById(final ID theId) {

        return entityManager.find(persistentClass, theId);
    }

    public final void persist(final T entity) {

        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public final void merge(final T entity) {

        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

And used 'ApplicationContextProvider' in 'AuditLogInterceptor' to get the reference of 'MyAuditDAO' that is having JPA entity manager as a property which is injected during DAO initialization. Now with the help of 'MyAuditDAO' I can perform database operations.

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {  

    @Override  
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) throws CallbackException {  

      // Here we can get the MyAuditDao reference and can perform persiste/merge options
       MyAuditDao myAuditDao = (MyAuditDao ) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("myAuditDao");

      //  myAuditDao.persist(myEntity);

    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it in JPA2 to get a reference to my auditLogRepository as using the @Resource annotation didn't inject anything and left me with an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering `persistenceManager` initiated successfully in your Abstract class. You may Have a class `AuditLogDAO` which extends your `AbstractDao`. Inject AuditLogDAO class into your interceptor and call `auditLogDAO.save(entity);` and other methods.

Or write a `Util` class which perform DB operations and inject the util class to your interceptor.